# Passing Variable in Qt from tab to tab in QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtabwidget

I am newbie to Qt and currently working on one QTabWidget which have two tabs means two widgets, as such

```
tabWidget->addTab(new First_Widget(),tr("Home"));
tabWidget->addTab(new Second_Widget(), tr("Download"));
```

First Widget have some integers and floats values which i want to use in the second  widget. I can make a constructor of second widget like this

```
tabWidget->addTab(new Second_Widget(argument1, argument2,argument3), tr("Download"));
```

and i think i can call second tab form the first widget but in that case the second tab will be hide until i don't click the respective button. Can anyone tell me how i can use first tab's values in the second.

Comment: Based on the comments in the answers, this feels like a home-work, and the OP does not seem to have the minimal understanding, so I am afraid voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain variables at tabWidget calling level. and pass variables by reference to both the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use emit-connect mechanism.

`First_Widget` emits signals when this integers and floats change and `Second_Widget` connects this signals to associated slots.

`Second_Widget` only has to know and interface that you can pass as constructor parameter:

```
// demo code, not tested
class IEmmiter
{
    Q_OBJECT
    signal:
       void Integer1Changed(int new_value);
       .....
};

class First_Widget : public IEmmiter
{

};

class Second_Widget
{
    Second_Widget(const IEmmiter & emmiter)
    {
        connect(&emmiter, SIGNAL(Integer1Changed(int)), this, SLOT(Integer1Changed(int)));
        ....
    }

};

// on your programm
auto fw = First_Widget();
auto sw = Second_Widget(*fw);

tabWidget->addTab(fw, tr("Home"));
tabWidget->addTab(sw, tr("Download"));
```

Comment: Sir, Truely speaking i didn't understand what this code is doing but i tried to implement this in my code but i got more than 50 errors..no idea what is going on.

Comment: @Hamid: Well, it is true that auto is excessive here since that makes the code C++11 compatible only or later, and the members are private without public specifier, but still, you should be able to start doing something with hints like this.

Comment: @Hamid, this is only an idea, won't compile, work on it. All Qt widely use signal-slots mechanism and if you want to improve your Qt knowledge you must understand it. It's so powerful and allows you to encapsulate your code and minimize dependencies.